# Не работает append_df_to_excel pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Доброго времени суток всем! Не могу записать DataFrame снизу уже существующего листа Excel. Есть такой код:

```
df = handbook_excel = pd.read_excel(r'/home/Desktop/План-Факт.xlsx')
df = df.loc[df['Вид'] == 'Факт']
df1 = df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 13','Год','Месяц','Сумма',], axis=1)
df1.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
path = r'/home/malik/Desktop/1234.xlsx'
```

Функция append_df_to_excel не работает от слова совсем: `NameError: name 'append_df_to_excel' is not defined`
Вот так пробовал, тоже ничего не получилось:

```
def append_pandas_to_excel(path, _df, starcol=1, startrow=1, sheet_name='Sheet1'):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    for row in range(0, len(_df)):
        for column in range(0, len(_df.iloc[row])):
            workbook[sheet_name].cell(startrow + row, starcol + column).value = _df.iloc[row][column]
            workbook.save(path)
```

pd.show_versions():

```
python           : 3.8.10.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Linux
OS-release       : 5.15.0-56-generic
Version          : #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP 
machine          : x86_64
processor        : x86_64
LANG             : en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE           : en_US.UTF-8

pandas           : 1.5.2
numpy            : 1.23.5
pytz             : 2022.6
dateutil         : 2.8.2
setuptools       : 60.2.0
pip              : 21.3.1
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : 3.0.3
openpyxl         : 3.0.10
```

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: `append_df_to_excel` не работает, ниже представлена функция `append_pandas_to_excel`. Так а первая где? К чему вы ошибку про неё написали?

Comment: К тому, что в документации есть стандартное решение `append_df_to_excel`. Я писал про него, `append_pandas_to_excel` - это мой костыль )